# Aurelia routing configuration issue

Tags: routes, aurelia

I am having an issue with configuring Aurelia route when the path like **layer1/layer2** not just **layer1**.
Here is the project file structure (files under dist gets created automatically based on files under src folder)

```
dist
    | - home
        | - home.html
        | - home.js
    | - user
        | - register.html
        | - register.js
    app.html
    app.js 
    main.js 
src
    | - home
        | - home.html
        | - home.js
    | - user
        | - register.html
        | - register.js
    app.html
    app.js 
    main.js
```

When I do the following it just works fine:

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="user">register user</a>
    <a href="otherlink">otherlink</a>
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
this.router.configure(config => {
  config.title = 'demo';
  config.options.pushState = true;
  config.map([
    // home routes
    { route: ['','home'], moduleId: './home/home', nav: true, title:'Home' },

    // User register
    { route: ['user'], moduleId: './user/register', nav: true, title:'Register User'}
  ]);
});
```

But when I change the path from **user** to **user/register** like below, it no longer works

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="user/register">register user</a>
    <a href="otherlink">otherlink</a>
  </div>
  <div class='main'>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
this.router.configure(config => {
  config.title = 'demo';
  config.options.pushState = true;
  config.map([
    // home routes
    { route: ['','home'], moduleId: './home/home', nav: true, title:'Home' },

    // User register
    { route: ['user/register'], moduleId: './user/register', nav: true, title:'Register User'}
  ]);
});
```

And in chrome debugger, I see this error:

GET http://localhost:9000/**user**/dist/user/register.html  404 (Not Found)

Notice that somehow an extra **user** gets added to the url which causes not to be able find register.html file. Again, when I am just using **user** as route, it works fine without any error but when I just change from **user** to **user/register**, it doesn't work anymore.

Could someone please let me know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Change the `href` for the link to be `href="#/user/register"` and that should clear up the issue for you.</strike>

I didn't see that you had pushState enabled. Please edit your `index.html` and add

```html
<base href="http://localhost:9000/">
```

Or whatever your root url is. This should fix the issue for you.

Comment: thank you for your response. However that didn't work. We added **config.options.pushState = true** to remove # sign from the url, so http://localhost:9000/user is accessible without #. But we can't make http://localhost:9000/user/register work even if route is set to **user/register** for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

I made a small change to Ashley's answer which makes little bit more environmentally friendly since we don't need to hard code local url. I tested it and works well too.

```html
<base href="/">
```